# look into a way to convert a string to date with python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a list of date with this format : `"190802  (2 august2019)"`.
I would like to format it to `"02-08-19"` using datetime. Is there a fucntion to do?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: Please post expected output of given sample along with what you have tried

Comment: `from datetime import datetime;d = datetime.strptime('190802', '%y%m%')` Will this work? Post your input and expected output

Comment: @Chris , thanks; The expected format is 02-08-19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you have a list of string inputs and you want to format them.

```
from datetime import datetime

input_list = ["190802  (2 august2019)"]

for input in input_list:
    date = datetime.strptime(input[:6], "%y%m%d")
    formated_output = date.strftime("%d-%m-%y")
    print(formated_output)

>>>'02-08-19'
```